# Purchased physical mac StarCraft 2 via amazon. Is it possible to download it prior dvd install?

Tags: starcraft-2, macos, battle.net

I purchased a copy of SC2 WoL from amazon.

The problem is that my old 2007 MBP dvd player is not that healthy anymore and I'm afraid I could have some problem with the installation. Or worse, destroy the disc.

So the question is: there is a way to notify this purchase to battle.net and download SC directly, without having to use the DVD at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an account at battle.net and then add the CD key for your game to your account. Then you'll be able to download and play without using the CD.

Comment: Even if you install it from the DVD, you won't need the DVD in the drive to play.

Comment: Yep, the game is attached to your Battle.net profile anyway, DVD just saves you the download.